# Apache says Error opening file for reading: Permission Denied

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to run a django (1.6) project with apache (2.2.22) and mod_wsgi (3.4). My python is 2.7.3, the ubuntu 12.04 default. I have set everything as chmod 777 from /var/www to downwards. Unfortunately it gives me

Error opening file for reading: Permission Denied
and then
Premature end of script headers: wsgi.py

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?
I am posting my error.log here

```
root@whq-4:/var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse# tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log 
[Tue Jan 14 14:16:04 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 14 14:16:08 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.3      configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 14 14:16:28 2014] [error] /var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
[Tue Jan 14 14:21:32 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers:   wsgi.py
[Tue Jan 14 14:29:13 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 14 14:29:13 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.3  configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 14 14:29:17 2014] [error] /var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
[Tue Jan 14 14:34:21 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers:  wsgi.py
```

And also my httpd.conf file

```
#LimitRequestLine 200475
#LimitRequestFieldSize 200475

WSGIDaemonProcess imse_dev2_wsgi python-path=/var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse


#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName whq-4
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    #Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Alias /static /var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/static
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/favicon.ico
#       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"


    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>


    WSGIScriptAlias /imse_dev2 /var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse/wsgi.py
    <Directory /var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse>
            WSGIProcessGroup imse_dev2_wsgi
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
             Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think that for apache 2.2 you should be using using mod_wsgi 3.3

Comment: ok ok, let me try then...

Comment: No idea at all, this might be a trivial question but I am struggling a lot

Comment: I searched a lot but still unsolved, apache2 cannot access my project's root directory anyway

Comment: No idea if that's it, but I notice that you have `/var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse` in `<Directory>` but the error is for `/var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse` (one less `Imse`). If that first path is correct, then it probably should not be trying to open `/var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse` as a file since it appears to be a directory.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, Django won't allow you to access files outside the directory where the application is.  So, for example, if your application is running at `/var/www/project` and the files you want to access is on `/var/www/foo`, Django will raises the exception you are getting.

The solution is to move the directory you are trying to access inside the project directory.

Comment: I think Django itself doesn't impose any restrictions on which files you can access... Do you mean Apache maybe?

Comment: Hi Mark, no, I really meant Django itself. It used to check whether you were trying to access something outside the project path... I had this problem myself before, but I can't confirm this checking is still in place in the current versions... but you can refer to Google for seeing how often it used to happen: https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=django%20file%20upload%20suspiciousoperation

Comment: Okay that's true, for uploaded files it checks the directory. I think Django checks that against MEDIA_ROOT rather than Apache conf though. I'm fairly sure that's not the problem here (no mention of a file being uploaded), but it's a good note, can cause similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your httpd.conf and the corresponding error message, looks like the directory

```
/var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse
```

is either *not* readable by the apache user (which 'owns' the apache process) or that directory isn't executable by the apache user. making that directory visible to all users can be done like this:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/Imse_dev2/Imse/Imse
```

but i would suspect there are other directories under your apache document root that would also be unreadable. i'd probably make all files and dirs owned by the apache user under your document root, unless you had specific reason not to, like this:

```
chown -R apache /var/www/Imse_dev2
```